# A certain Lie algebra associated to a bialgebra

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras, bialgebras

Let $A$ be a bialgebra over a field $k$. The space $A^* = \operatorname{Hom}(A, k)$ possesses an algebra structure, given by the convolution product $f*g = f \otimes g \circ \Delta$.
Let $\gamma \in A^*$ be an idempotent, i.e. $\gamma * \gamma = \gamma$, i.e. $\gamma$ is a comultiplicative map from $A$ to $k$ (but not necessarily counital).

We could call $\delta \in \operatorname{End}_k(A)$ satisfying
\begin{align*}
\delta(ab) = \delta(a)b + \gamma(a_1) a_2 \delta(b)
\end{align*}
a "derivation up to $\gamma$" or something like that.
Here I'm using a sumless Sweedler-type notation.

Now I want to put another condition $(P_\gamma)$, which is: $\delta$ should satisfy
$$
\gamma(a_1) \delta(a_2) = \gamma(\delta(a_1)) \delta(a_2)\ .
$$

With these conditions one computes:

> **Lemma.** The usual commutator turns the space of derivations up to $\gamma$
> satisfying condition $(P_\gamma)$ into a Lie-algebra

I have two (dependent) questions:

- Is this trivial? I've only checked in one example, namely the group Hopf algebra of the cyclic group of order 2. There is one non-trivial choice for $\gamma$, and then there's only one endomorphism satisfying $(P_\gamma)$, but it is not a "derivation up to $\gamma$".

I can't see why it should be trivial in general.

- If it's not trivial, then people must have thought about it before.
  Can anyone point me to a reference?

---

PS: Without writing out all my thoughts, the condition for $\gamma$ to be an idempotent could probably be replaced to $\gamma$ being central in $A^*$.
But that leads to another structure.

---

**Edit:**
I have computed for some other group algebras of cyclic groups, and just finished a computation in Sweedler's Hopf algebra. The space of endomorphisms satisfying both conditions was always zero (I have not tried each idempotent of the dual, though).
This saddens me.

Comment: Presumably you are defining 1-cocycles for a particular bimodule structure on A, where the left action is $a\cdot_\gamma x = \gamma(a_{(1)})a_{(2)} x$? I am not sure I can interpret the second condition, but 1-cocycles tend to be form Lie algebras.

Comment: Something like that, but not quite. Your $\cdot_{\gamma}$ will not necessarily be an associative action, because I did not require $\gamma$ to be an algebra map. In fact, I'm fairly sure that in the Hopf algebra case, this requirement would force $\gamma$ to be the counit (since it will then be an invertible idempotent). The second condition was sufficient to make the lemma true, and I don't have an interpretation. [The ambitious goal was to arrive at "Hochschild up to $\gamma$", but trouble early on..]